# Solve the equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$x\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 - \dfrac{dy}{dx} = x^4$$

I tried to integrate both sides w.r.t $x$, but it seems the resulting expressions are actually more complicated.

EDIT: Treating this as a quadratic in $dy/dx$, we have the discriminant $4x^5 + 1$. If we ask for rational solutions, there should exist a rational $m$ such that $4x^5 + 1 = m^2$. Hence, the question is now on the rational solutions to the equation $4x^5 + 1 = m^2$.

Comment: It's a quadratic equation: solve for $dy/dx$ using the classic formula. You will then get $dy/dx = g(x)$ for some function $x$ which can be integrated directly.

Comment: @Winther. The integration of $g(x)$ does not look very pleasant to me. Any idea on your side ?

Comment: If you ask for rational solutions, shouldn't $m \geqslant 0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think substituting $\sqrt{1+4x^5}$ should work. With $z= \sqrt{1+4x^5}$ the integrand becomes $\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}dx \to \frac{2 z^2}{5 \left(z^2-1\right)}dz$ which is easy to handle ($\text{\arctanh}$ solution).

Comment: @Winther. Fo sure; but  $\sqrt{1+4x^5}=?$

Comment: I was wondering; what's wrong with setting $y$ as a polynomial of degree 4 and then solving for its coefficients?

Comment: @Winther. You are totally right ! I missed it. I was thinking about $z^2$. Cheers.

Comment: @Ant If $y$ has degree $n$ then $x(dy/dx)^2 - (dy/dx)$ has degree $2n-1$ which cannot be equal to $4$.

Comment: @Winther cool observation! Thank you :-)

Comment: "If we ask for rational solutions": what do you call a rational solution, this is nonsense ???

Comment: Seriously do we have to start explaining what a rational solution is on SE ?

Comment: Think twice before writing such comments.

Comment: Hahah look who is talking ! If i have to think twice, then you have to think (at least) 1000 times.

Comment: Please explain what you call a rational solution.

Comment: Explaining such a trivial statement at this level, like seriously ????

Comment: Do you mean rational-only solution ? This cannot occur with a non-constant continuous function.

Comment: No. Not counting the insult that you discarded, the necessary clarifications belong to the problem statement, not to side discussions.

Comment: Insult ????  Who started by saying ''nonsense'' ?? Which was not even justified anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$x\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2-\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=x^4\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xy'(x)^2-y'(x)=x^4\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xy'(x)^2-y'(x)-x^4=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Using the 'quadratic formula':

---

$$y'(x)=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\cdot x\cdot (-x^4)}}{2\cdot x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1--4x(x^4)}}{2\cdot x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2\cdot x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int y'(x)\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2x}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\int\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2x}\space\text{d}x$$

---

For the integrals, notice:

$$\int\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\right]\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}\space\text{d}x+\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}\space\text{d}x+\ln|x|\right]$$

---

$$\int\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{2x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}\right]\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x-\int\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}\space\text{d}x\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln|x|-\int\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^5}}{x}\space\text{d}x\right]$$

Comment: @Isaac. Maybe there is, but evaluate the integral and look for them :)